# how to make a function return true or false into another function

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

I'm currently trying to setup authentication on my application. I have a function in the state storage(pinia) that checks if the user is authenticated or not. I want the function to return true or false which is passed onto the navigation guard which then allows or doesn't allow the user to continue in the app.

```
import { ref, computed, watch } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios'
import router from '../router'

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:4003'


export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {
    const user = ref ({
        username: "",
        id: "",
        isUserLoggedin: false,
        email: "",
        authToken: "",
        authenticated: false,
        role: ""
    })
    const checkAuth = async () => {
      try
      {
        await axios.post('/api/authCheck', {}, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${user.value.authToken}`
            }
          })
        .then(({ data: userData }) => {
          user.value.authenticated = true
          user.value.isUserLoggedin = true
          user.value.role = userData.user_type
          return true
        })
      } catch(err)
      {
        user.value.username = ""
        user.value.id = ""
        user.value.isUserLoggedin = false
        user.value.email = ""
        user.value.authToken = ""
        user.value.authenticated = false
        user.value.role = ""
        router.push('/auth/login')
        console.log(err)
        return false
      }
    }
    return {
        user,
        checkAuth
    }
},
{
    persist: true
})
```

This is the router guard

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // if (to.name !== 'Login' && !isAuthenticated) next({ name: 'Login' })
  // else next()
  const store = useUserStore()
  const authResult = store.checkAuth()
  console.log(authResult)
  if(to.meta.requiresAuth && !store.checkAuth())
  next({name: 'dash.home'})
  else next()
})
```

When I console log authResult I see it returns a promise, I'm not sure how to make it just return true or false...

Comment: `checkAuth` is an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). You need to `await` it to get the returned value

Answer (score 1):

There can be a workaround like this. Take another boolean variable say `check`. Now check the value returned by `authResult`, if the value is `not null` make `check=true` else make `check=false`. Now you can simply use `check` variable. Hope it helps.